# Is the cardinals of $P(P(\Bbb{N}))$ $C$ or $2^C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let us look at $P(P(\Bbb{N}))$. Is the cardinals $C$ or $2^C$? Really confusing...

Comment: If $C$ is the cardinality of the continuum, you have $|P(\mathbb{N})|=C$. Then you know that $|P(X)|=2^{|X|}$, so…

Comment: You are right. Except someone said that it is $2^{2^\aleph_0}=2^{2\cdot \aleph_0 }=C$ and he wouldn't agree with me at all... And everyone is taking his side. 
Oh well it sounds like a kindergarten.

Comment: Sounds like someone is wrong. And even confusing $\mathfrak c^2$ and $2^\mathfrak c$.

Comment: Whoever said that $2^C=C$ is *very* wrong. Maybe there's some confusion with the argument that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: I think a good argument in that disucssion could be the one hinted at in both answers: the cardinality of a powers set of a set is *always* larger then the cardinality of the set. Apply this to $P(N)$. Whatever it is precisely, the cardinalty of $P(P(N))$ must be larger than that of $P(N)$.

Comment: I guess.. 
It would contradict the result of many years of work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cardinality of $\mathcal P(X)$ is $2^{|X|}$. So we do this in steps:$$|\cal P(P(\Bbb N))|=2^{|P(\Bbb N)|}=2^\frak c.$$

Answer (score 2):

The cardinal of the powerset of the natural numbers is the cardinality of the continuum. When you take again the powerset you get the cardinality of the power set of the continuum, that is $2^C$.

In any case, the cardinality of a powerset of a set is always larger than the cardinality of the set. This also applies to the case that the set is $P(\mathbb{N})$.